# how to change font of menu in fruitful wordpress theme?

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, font-face, font-family

I want to change all the fonts to special elite font in my website. So I have used wp google font plugin. It worked well with all other text except Menu. I want to change the menu fonts to special elite font. How can I do that?  Any other alternative for that? Is is possible to add special elite font in the options of the fruitful theme? link to my site http://mycompany.co.nf/2/

Comment: Try this .main-navigation a{font-family: 'Special Elite', arial, sans-serif !important;}